# Access Padrino settings from controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sinatra, padrino

I am trying to get values from Padrino.configure_apps block in config/apps.rb, but Sinatra way not working here.
Anyone know the Padrino way to access the settings from controller ?
Thankx in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so i've defined all in ./app/app.rb file and it can be accessed via settings.xxx format.